# Move numbers at the beginning of the line to the end of the line

Tags: awk, sed, text-processing

I have an output from Unix `uniq -c` command which prints the number of occurrences of a string at the beginning of each line. The string represents two authors separated by a pipe (e.g., `Aabdel-Wahab S|Abdel-Hafeez EH`).

```
  1 Aabdel-Wahab S|Abdel-Hafeez EH
  1 Aabdel-Wahab S|Abdulla AM
  4 Aabdel-Wahab S|Ahmad AK
  1 Aabdel-Wahab S|Mosalem FA
  1 Aabye MG|Andersen AB
  8 Aabye MG|Changalucha J
  1 Aabye MG|Christensen DL
  1 Aabye MG|Faurholt-Jepsen D
```

I need to grep the occurrence number and move it to the end of the line. For example:

```
Aabdel-Wahab S|Abdel-Hafeez EH|1
Aabdel-Wahab S|Abdulla AM|1
Aabdel-Wahab S|Ahmad AK|4
Aabdel-Wahab S|Mosalem FA|1
Aabye MG|Andersen AB|1
Aabye MG|Changalucha J|8
Aabye MG|Christensen DL|1
Aabye MG|Faurholt-Jepsen D|1
```

Please note that frequencies are now pipe delimited. Pasted below is my one-liner in Awk:

```
awk '{num=$1;$1=""; sub(/^ /,""); print $0,"|",num;}' file
```

However the Awk add extra spaces around the final pipeline:

```
Aabdel-Wahab S|Abdel-Hafeez EH | 1
Aabdel-Wahab S|Abdulla AM | 1
Aabdel-Wahab S|Ahmad AK | 4
Aabdel-Wahab S|Mosalem FA | 1
Aabye MG|Andersen AB | 1
Aabye MG|Changalucha J | 8
Aabye MG|Christensen DL | 1
Aabye MG|Faurholt-Jepsen D | 1
```

Any idea how to proceed (not necessary using Awk)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `printf`:

```
awk '{num=$1;$1=""; sub(/^ /,""); printf("%s|%s\n",$0,num);}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a true case for using `sed` instead of `awk`:

```
sed 's/^  *\([0-9][0-9]*\) *\(.*\)/\2|\1/' file
```

Regex breakdown:

- `^  *` Start with at least one space
- `\(` Start of  capturing group one

  - `[0-9][0-9]*` Match at least one digit
- `\)` End of CG one
- `*` Any number of space characters
- `\(.*\)` Capture rest of input line (CG two)

Replacement string changes order of capturing groups with a single `|` between.

Comment: Agreed. sed is the right tool for simple substitutions on individual lines like this.

Answer (score 2):

Awks not adding spaces by itself, you're **telling** awk to add spaces. What do you think `,` means in `print 1,2` (hint: look up `OFS` in the awk man page)? Just don't do that:

```
awk '{num=$1; $1=""; sub(/^ /,""); print $0 "|" num}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/\s*([0-9]+)\s*(.*)/\2|\1/' infile
```

- The `\s*` matches zero-or-more whitespaces.
- The `([0-9]+)` matches one-or-more digits and parentheses used for group match.
- The `(.*)` matches anything and parentheses used for group match again here also.
- In `\2|\1`, we are printing second group match i.e `(.*)`, next first group match i.e `([0-9]+)` with pipe between.

POSIXly, you would do:

```
sed 's/^ *\([0-9][0-9]*\) *\(.*\)$/\2|\1/' infile
```